# Remove old Adobe Flash code from wordpress posts

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I want to automatically remove that old (unused) code from old WordPress posts with the PHP function.

The code:

```
<object height="18" width="100%"><param name="movie" value="https://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F52492692&amp;auto_play=false&amp;player_type=tiny&amp;font=Arial&amp;color=333333"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"><param name="wmode" value="transparent"><embed wmode="transparent" allowscriptaccess="always" height="18" src="https://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F52492692&amp;auto_play=false&amp;player_type=tiny&amp;font=Arial&amp;color=333333" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%"></object>
```

I have many posts with that code; how it's possible to get rid of it?

Thank you for your time and help.
George

I have searched on Google to find a similar solution but have not found anything related how can I remove the code:

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish this using at least one of two straightforward methods (there are others methods to solve it).

**Solution 1:**

You can easily remove this code using a filter, and it won't be visible on the site (in the WP editor or when using the function `the_content()`). However, the code will be removed from the database only after a manual update. Additionally, the code can still be visible when using the function `get_the_content()` or accessing `$post->post_content` or through other similar methods that work without filters.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_object');
add_filter('the_editor_content', 'filter_object');
function filter_object($content = '') {
    return preg_replace('/<object\b[^>]*>.*<\/object>/i', '', $content);
}
```

**Solution 2:**

You can remove the code from the database using this function. Simply copy this code into the 'functions.php' file and open the URL: https://yoursite.com/?start=1

```
add_action( 'init', function () {
    if ( isset( $_GET['start'] ) ) {
        $offset         = !empty($_GET['offset']) ? intval($_GET['offset']) : 0;
        $posts_per_page = 100;
        echo 'offset: ' . $offset . '<br />';
        $posts = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type'      => 'post',
            'post_status'    => 'any',
            'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
            'offset'         =>  $offset,
            'orderby'        => 'ID',
            'order'          => 'ASC',
        ) );
        if ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
                $posts->the_post();
                global $post;
                $post_content    = $post->post_content;
                $updated_content = preg_replace('/<object\b[^>]*>.*<\/object>/i', '', $post_content);
                echo get_the_ID();
                if ( $post_content !== $updated_content ) {
                    $post->post_content = $updated_content;
                    wp_update_post($post);
                    echo ' updated';
                }
                echo '<br />';
            }
            ?>
            <script>
                setTimeout(() => {
                    window.location.href = '?start=1&offset=<?php echo $offset + $posts_per_page; ?>';
                }, 1000);
            </script>
            <?php
        } else {
            echo 'no posts';
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
        die();
    }
} );
```

I believe solution 2 is better, but it might take some time if your site has a large number of posts.

Comment: Hello, I have around 150K posts, but the code remains only for older posts.
If possible to run that function and cover only posts from 2015 to 2009.
That will be great in terms of server load, time etc.

Comment: Hello! Yes, this function can handle any number of posts since it utilizes JavaScript reloading, and each iteration processes only 100 posts. If you want to include posts from 2015 to 2009, you can use the [date_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters). Here's an [example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/102279/wp-query-parameters-for-date-range) for your reference.